# How to get access to mic on Google Home device?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I want make a simple app (action) on Google Home speaker but I cannot find any docs in which is described how to get access to mic.

Is there any chance to develop VoIP app on the Google Home device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - no. (Or at least not at this time.)

The only access Google provides third-party built apps is through Actions on Google, and this does not provide direct access to the microphone or to an audio stream.